# Check or uncheck all radio inputs by id on radio yes/no selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My issue is that i cannot edit the form code output so would like to target radio ids to check or uncheck depending on if a different radio button is selected. Would this is be possible? - i can add a function call on the  tag or use jquery - but i cannot edit the form code itself like adding onclick events.

Pseudo code would be:

```
If #unsubYes is checked Then
uncheck #option1Yes + #option2Yes AND
check #option1No + #option2No

If #unsubNo is checked Then
uncheck #option1No + #option2No AND
check #option1Yes + #option2Yes
```

[Link to JS fiddle html](https://jsfiddle.net/0v8djdb0/)

Any help appreciated.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Very possible, yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i can do it with a onclick event, but not sure how to make it fire otherwise

Comment: Have you looked at other event listeners and tried them? If so then which ones? Could you include the relevant source code with your attempt please. That will give others something to look at, work with and debug. Maybe then explain why your attempt isn't functioning as intended and then also offer a solution to fit your needs. Without seeing what you have or your attempt it's impossible to explain why it isn't working or give you a solid  answer/solution to learn from.

Comment: Thanks for replying, im very much a novice at JS so i've just been hacking together an example from other answers i have seen on google and stack community. Although the example works below i have now run into a issue where it doenst work once place on my page where the form is generated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004701/generated-form-not-liking-javascript-change-field-value-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("[name='unsub']").on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var reverseVal = (val == 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes')
    $("input[value='"+reverseVal+"']:not([name='unsub'])").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<span>Option 1</span><br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1Yes" value="Yes">
  Yes
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1No" value="No">
  No
</label>
<br /><br />
<span>Option 2</span><br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2Yes" value="Yes">
  Yes
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2No" value="No">
  No
</label>
<hr />
<span>Unsubscribe from all</span><br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="unsub" id="unsubYes" value="Yes">
  Yes
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="unsub" id="unsubNo" value="No">
  No
</label>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thats great @Emīls Gulbis - but is there a way to reverse the radios that are being checked? Currently clicking unsub yes ticks yes radios when it should tick no radios (and vice versa)

Comment: Thanks so much!! legend

Comment: Hi again @Emīls Gulbis - For some reason the logic does not work when i add it to my generated form (although works fine in JSfiddle) -
 see: http://www.pages05.net/ps_tiobeptyltd/js-tes
 - wondering if you have any ideas or if there is a messier way to do it like targeting the option1 and option2 names?

Comment: Code is loaded too late.
Try to add code bottom or wrap it in $(function() {//code here})

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course is possible.
You could do something similar like this

```
document.querySelector('#unsubYes').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // do something if is checked
    } else {
        // do other thins
    }
});
```