# Generated form not liking javascript change field value function

Tags: javascript, html

I was previously helped to get a javscript function using jquery working - see :
[JS Fiddle working example](https://jsfiddle.net/0v8djdb0/7/)

```js
$("[name='COLUMN35']").on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var reverseVal = (val == 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes')
  $("input[value='" + reverseVal + "']:not([name='COLUMN35'])").prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Option 1</span><br />
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1Yes" value="Yes">Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option1" id="option1No" value="No">No</label>
<br /><br />
<span>Option 2</span><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2Yes" value="Yes">Yes
</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option2" id="option2No" value="No">No</label>
<hr />
<span>Unsubscribe from all</span><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="COLUMN35" id="unsubYes" value="Yes">Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="COLUMN35" id="unsubNo" value="No">No</label>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Upon implmenting that same code into the generated form page i am not sure why it does not work - see:
[Webform with code not working](http://www.pages05.net/ps_tiobeptyltd/js-tes)

Unfortunately I am not able to edit the any of the form elements as they are generated automatically but hoping someone might have a different idea to implement - usually the messier the better E.G target the relevant ids to change  and maybe not using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting your code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`
eg

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[name='COLUMN35']").on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var reverseVal = (val == 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes')
    $("input[value='"+reverseVal+"']:not([name='COLUMN35'])").prop('checked', true);
});
});
```